# Поиск похожих фраз

Tags: php, массивы, строки, парсер, динамические-массивы

Меня интересует такой момент. Парсю я к примеру 2 сайта, у них одинаковые категории но по разному написаны.

Например:

> 1 сайт: Ножи туристические
>   2 сайт: Туристические ножи

Это одинаковые категории но по другому написаны.
Категории все записываются в массив, но перед записью нужно проверить массив на наличие подобного рода вхождений.

Как быть в такой ситуации?

Comment: Поделить на токены, подровнять регистр, сравнить.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под токенами?

Comment: В данном конкретном случае токеном, вероятно, нужно считать слово.

Comment: Использовать морфологию. В Интернет можно найти открытые библиотеки

Comment: Я уже думал о сравнении. Но Вы понимаете, что категория может быть и "Охотничьи ножи" и сравнивать по "ножи" не очень.

Comment: Если категории из примера привести в нижний регистр, поделить на слова в массив, его отсортировать и слить обратно - обе дадут `ножи туристические`. Что не совпадёт с `ножи охотничьи`.

Comment: Приведите все варианты комплиментарных фраз, чтоб было ясно с какими кейсам коду придется иметь дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ещё без сортировки массива - переворачивать его элементы:

```
$str_1 = 'Ножи туристические';
$str_2 = 'Туристические ножи';

var_dump( similar_str($str_1, $str_2) );


function similar_str(... $data)
{
    [$a, $b] = array_map('mb_strtolower', $data);
    $b = join(' ', array_reverse(explode(' ', $b)));
    return $a == $b;
}
```

---

**UPD:** Как выяснилось, вариант с array_reverse() подходит только для пары слов, поэтому я дописал сортировку, как и было предложено в комментариях:

```
$str_1 = 'Ножи какие-то туристические';
$str_2 = 'Туристические ножи какие-то';

var_dump( similar_str($str_1, $str_2) );


function similar_str(... $data)
{
    [$a, $b] = array_map(function($i){
        $words = explode(' ', mb_strtolower($i));
        sort($words);
        return $words;
    }, $data);

    return $a == $b;
}
```